# Rails/Heroku... can I change the procfile programatically?

Tags: heroku, scalability, procfile

I have a procfile on my Heroku system designed to allow me to scale workers.  The problem I have is that I want to scale workers not known about at the time of writing.  Ie I can't hard code them.

I want to be able to create a new worker type on the fly on Heroku.
I want to have a worker per client.  Or perhaps many workers for a client that has a heavier load. 
Each client pays for their own worker.

All examples of the proc file have three different queues "normal", "priority".
What I want though is different queues per client. 
"client_1", "client_2", "client_3"....

I suppose I could build a procfile with 2000 entries... but that feels ugly.

Okay.. so my question.
Can I have my rails app modify the procfile, during run time?  Add new lines to account for new clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Heroku doesn't support specifying new process types dynamically.

However, are you sure that's really what you want to do? Why does each client need a different queue? If you leave a worker process running, it will perform jobs for any client that requests them. If you're trying to segregate client environments, maybe multiple apps are a better solution?

Comment: My app is a large data warehouse.  If client X is editing 100k records and client Y is editing 100 records.  Client Y shouldn't have to wait for client X to be finished their task.  The segmentation idea would lead to maintaining 1000+ apps.. it is not attractive.  I can imagine the effort needed to update the apps

Comment: ps that 100k vs 100 record thing happened last week (okay 87k vs 126), and I currently have three clients.  Client Y was not happy, as they expected 126 records would take less than an hour :)

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, maybe using a Hadoop–style add-on might help solve the problem. Something like https://addons.heroku.com/treasure-data?

Comment: *Or*, as a really naive approach, schedule jobs with `priority=number_of_records_to_modify`, if you know that in advance. Small jobs jump the queue, and probably don't noticeably impact larger jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has a platform API 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference

that might do what you want.  I haven't tried it yet, but the Formation and Dyno endpoints seem to be able to be manipulated directly on runtime.